# Why can't I use the function floor?

Tags: haskell

My code:

```
getDateFromUser :: IO (Either UserError UTCTime)
getDateFromUser = do
  Prelude.putStrLn "Пожалуйста, укажите дату для прогноза в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД:"
  currentTime <- getCurrentTime
  date        <- Prelude.getLine
  let dayFromUser = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d" date :: Maybe UTCTime
  case dayFromUser of
    Nothing -> return $ Left InvalidDate
    Just validDay -> do
       let differenceInNominalDiffTime = diffUTCTime validDay currentTime
           differenceInDays            = floor $ differenceInNominalDiffTime / nominalDay
       if  differenceInNominalDiffTime >= 0 && differenceInNominalDiffTime <= 16
           then return $ Right validDay
           else return $ Left InvalidDate
```

Without `floor` this code is compiled. But but with `floor` i get this error

```
Defaulting the following constraint to type ‘Integer’
    Integral b0 arising from a use of ‘floor’
• In the expression:
    floor $ differenceInNominalDiffTime / nominalDay
  In an equation for ‘differenceInDays’:
      differenceInDays = floor $ differenceInNominalDiffTime / nominalDay
  In the expression:
    do let differenceInNominalDiffTime
             = diffUTCTime validDay currentTime
           differenceInDays = floor $ differenceInNominalDiffTime / nominalDay
       if differenceInNominalDiffTime >= 0
            && differenceInNominalDiffTime <= 16 then
           return $ Right validDay
       else
           return $ Left InvalidDate
```

`37 |            differenceInDays            = floor $ differenceInNominalDiffTime / nominalDay`

What is this error and how to fix it?

Comment: AFAIK that text should be prefixed by  `Warning:` which tells you that *this is not an error*. The code is compiling fine. Your problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892249/avoid-warning-defaulting-the-following-constraints-to-type-integer). You could fix it by adding type signatures on the relevant functions/variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid warning Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type \`Integer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892249/avoid-warning-defaulting-the-following-constraints-to-type-integer)

Comment: N.B. you aren't using `differenceInDays` at all. Assuming you intended to use it in your `if` condition, though, there's no reason to call `floor` anyway: `floor x >= 0 && floor x <= 16` is the same as `x >= 0 && x < 17` for any sensible type.